# How do I insert field values from database into an HTML table using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, indy10

I'm generating a HTML order confirmation email using the `TIdMessage` Indy component in Delphi XE6.

I can add a line to my `TIdMessage` using:

```
IdMessage1.Body.Text := '<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0.2in"><FONT COLOR="#FF0000"><FONT FACE="Calibri"><B> Order Confirmation for Work Order # ' + MyDatasetNameWorkOrder.AsString + '</B></FONT></FONT></P><P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0.2in"><FONT FACE="Calibri">Hello ' + OrdersForm.Proper(ServiceContact1DBText.Field.AsString) + ',</FONT></FONT></P>';`
```

and then add my HTML head/body sections after those lines, and the resulting email works.  It displays the proper Work Order # and Contact when displayed as a HTML email.

But if I add the code above to the body section of my HTML email it doesn't show the table value for the Work Order #, or the Contact person.  It just shows the actual text like `+ MyDatasetNameWorkOrder.AsString + and  + OrdersForm.Proper(ServiceContact1DBText.Field.AsString) +` in that area of the email.

Do I have to wrap those lines with some other code when trying to embed or insert a database value in a HTML paragraph or table?

Comment: You already [asked this on the Embarcadero forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=249835) and got answers to it, so why are you asking the same question here?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - Yes,sorry! I actually posted here first, but then realized that the question would be better served being posted to the Embarcadero forum as it's less a HTML question and more a Delphi question.  Is there a way to delete it from here?

Comment: You posted it, you have the [option to delete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/).

Comment: What's the problem with asking in both places?  SO users can benefit.. I personally don't use the EMB forums..

Comment: @JohnEasley: it is considered rude to cross-post the same thing across multiple forums at the same time without waiting for a reply first.  And it wastes the time of the people replying, if the requester gets their answer somewhere else. Forums (including SO) are not real-time.  If you post a question somewhere, have the decency to give people some time to reply before going elsewhere.